# Confused between HAS-A and representation

Tags: object-oriented, c++, composition

I'm currently working on a game in which a maths module is being used, here is one of the classes called Vertex.

I'm getting confused with the relationship between HAS-A and objects representation.

I know that HAS-A is the composition of the object, but what has the composition got to do with the objects representation?

The vertex object here is represented by a 2d point as its position, but it could also be said that the vertex HAS-A position. Which route should i take? Do i design class attributes as HAS-A or as a representation?

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex(Maths::Point position);
    ~Vertex();
    
private:
    Maths::Point position; // is this supposed to be HAS-A or representation?
};
```

Here is another example from the GUI module, should the attributes be HAS-A or representation?

```
class Label
{
public:
    Label();
    ~Label();
    
private:
    Maths::Shapes::Rectangle bounds;
    std::string text;
    int fontSize;
};
```

Comment: By representation do you mean IS-A or something else? It's been used a number of ways.

Comment: Representation as the private data attributes

Comment: So as represented in memory or when serialized?

Comment: I think you might be overthinking this.  IS-A and HAS-A are simply metaphors for composition and inheritance, nothing more than that.

Comment: @RichardBamford I asked if you meant as represented in memory, or when serialized, because these representations are not limited by encapsulation or implementation hiding. It's very different from an objects public representation.

Comment: Richard, I don't understand the question. You showed us a class design and asked *"is this supposed to be HAS-A or representation?"* - what precisely do you think would be the difference? Do you mean how this particular design should be called? Or do you mean the design you showed us is something you would call "HAS-A design" - and a "representation design" would look different? Or vice versa? Please clarify.

Comment: @DocBrown Hi thanks for the reply, yes exactly, what would the difference look like between a "HAS-A" design and a "representation design"?

Comment: What is a "representation design?"  HAS-A is just an informal term describing "Composition."  See [here](https://stackify.com/oop-concepts-composition/#:~:text=Composition%20is%20one%20of%20the,has%2Da%20association%20between%20objects.).

Comment: @RobertHarvey So the object's HAS-A is not the object's entire representation? Therefore the object has some attributes that are compositions and others that are to represent the object?

Comment: No. HAS-A means the same thing here  as it does everywhere else.  A car "HAS-A" steering wheel.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean by "representation design?"

Comment: What do *you* mean by these terms, what design method presentation are you getting them from, and where are you stuck applying them according to those meanings & that method? PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: "So the object's HAS-A is not the object's entire representation? Therefore the object has some attributes that are compositions and others that are to represent the object? " - it's unclear how are you making this distinction. Composition (has-a) just means that you are using smaller things to build bigger things, like with legos. Maths::Point is composed out of 2 (or 3) float-s; a vertex is composed of a point representing position, a color, a vector representing uv coordinates, etc. 1/2

Comment: A representation is just how you choose to represent some concept; e.g., you could represent vertex position internally with a Maths::point, or directly with 3 float-s for `(x, y, z)`, or maybe you'd use double-s, or maybe for a certain kind of application you'd use polar coordinates, or maybe you'd use big integers. The distinction perhaps makes sense when you're separating responsibilities, delegating some of the work to some nontrivial subobject (i.e., to something that has its own behavior, something that'd be interesting as a separate class in a UML diagram). 2/2

Comment: P.S. In other words, the fact that an object *has* something ("has-a") just means that you've chosen that particular way to represent the concept that the containing object models. In principle, as soon as you put a member field in an object, you have a "has-a" relationship with that field, but we're usually more interested in cases where such a member field is a proper object in its own right, so we emphasize those "has-a" relationships. The fact that an object has an instance of another object as a subelement is a part of (or a fact about) its representation.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

> The vertex object here is represented by a 2d point as its position, but it could also be said that the vertex HAS-A position.

so let's try to explain what both of these statements mean:

- "X is represented by Y" means that a thing X might be substituted by Y. For example, an object of type `Maths::Point` could represent (or substitute) a vertex. This description fits, too, when one does not use a class `Vertex` at all, just variables of type `Maths::Point` which are used for storing vertices. Another way of describing is: inside a class `Vertex`, the "(idea of a) vertex" is represented by a `Maths::Point` object.
- "X HAS-A Y" means, a class X contains ("has") a member variable of type Y. So `Vertex` has-a member variable of type `Maths::Point`. `Label` has-a variable bounds of type `Maths::Shapes::Rectangle`, it has-a variable `text` of type `std::string`, and it has-a variable `fontSize` of type `int`. Together, the triple `(bounds, text, fontSize)` *represent* a label, and to express this kind of representation explicitly in a programming language like C++, one can put these variables into a class named `Label`.

My point is: these two kind of descriptions are **neither mutual exclusive, nor do they describe different kind of designs**. Those are just different wordings for some slightly different aspects of the same design. So don't overthink this.

Comment: Your definition of "representation" is not at all aligned with the C++ definition of representation. Since OP has a tag C++ and C++ code, I understand that the C++ term prevails.

Comment: @Christophe: regardless of the tag, I don't think the OP meant "representation" in the sense of "representation of C++ types by underlying bits and bytes", but in a more general manner.  If you meant something different, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the word "composition" that is tripping you up.

Composition in object orientated design means essentially that objects should be made up of other objects. They should be composed of other objects. Anything that is "in" the object for want of a better term, should also be an object (or use inheritance, but I don't think your question is about inheritance)

So take your Vertex.

Yes it is represented by a 2d point. But *that* 2d point is also an object. The Vertex *has a* Point called "position". That is how its position is represented.

This can be a little confusing in languages that are not true object orientated languages like C++ or Java where you can have a Vertex either be represented by 2 integer values or be represented by a specific instance of another object (in this case Point)

It is clearer in languages like Ruby or Smalltalk where everything is an object including primitives like integers. In such languages it is impossible not to represent an object in terms of other objects composed together to form the main object (or represent them as children of parent objects, again see inheritance).

So there isn't a difference between the objects representation and "has a". The objects representation *is* what objects it has and what it does with them (its behaviour).

Answer (score -4):

The particular case of a `point` probably is not a good example of this concept.  It's too specialized.

Better example might be:  "a `car` ***is*** **a** `thing_with_wheels` *(which might encompass more things than a "parent class" such as `vehicle`)*, and it ***has*** **a** `position`."

Comment: I see people are still trying to answer this question.

Comment: The question is not about "IS-A vs. HAS-A" - still most answers here try to explain this, which was actually not asked.